# Django Template not loading the view inside another template

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to include another template inside my home page as follows:

```
{% if user.userorganisation.organisation %}
    {% include 'organisation_members.html' %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'create_organisation.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

The create_organisation template is correctly loading its view so the step of checking the organisation of the user is correct.
When I am trying to directly access the organisation_members.html url everything is working fine but when I am inside the home page where the include 'organisation_members.html' exists, only the static contents are being loaded.

I have tried adding some prints for debugging and the view is not being called at all. Here is the view:

```
def organisation_members(request):
   print("aaaaaa")
   try:
       print("aaaaaaaa")
       user_organisation = UserOrganisation.objects.get(user=request.user)
       print(user_organisation.organisation)
       organisation_users = UserOrganisation.objects.filter(
           organisation=user_organisation.organisation).select_related('user')

       print(organisation_users)
       context = {
           'organisation_users': organisation_users,
       }
       return render(request, 'organisation_members.html', context)

   except UserOrganisation.DoesNotExist:
       return redirect('some_error_page')
```

And here is the url:

```
path('organisation_members/', views.organisation_members,name='organisation_members'),
```

Why is the view not being called when including the html page? I know that the 'include' only includes the html but why is it that the create_organisation.html being called and the organisation_members not, when I am doing the same exact steps in both of them

Comment: If the included template needs a special context, you have to provide this context on your homepage as well. Including a template does not execute the _other_ view.

Comment: a template will not call a view function - when you include it, its basically the same thing as copying all the code in that template and pasting it in the page where you used the include command. In your view function for the page you have the include in, you need to make sure you have the same context as the page that does not.